# Tidy text: Compute Zipf's law from the following term-document matrix

Tags: r, tidytext, zipf

I tried the code from http://tidytextmining.com/tfidf.html. My result can be seen in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2CTf.jpg).

My question is: How can I rewrite the code to produce the negative relationship between the term frequency and the rank?

The following is the term-document matrix. Any comments are highly appreciated.

```
 # Zipf 's law

freq_rk < -DTM_words %>%
group_by(document) %>%
mutate(rank=row_number(),
       'term_frequency'=count/total)

freq_rk %>%
ggplot(aes(rank,term_frequency,color=document)) +
geom_line(size=1.2,alpha=0.8)


DTM_words
 # A tibble: 4,530 x 5
     document       term count     n total
        <chr>      <chr> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
 1        1      activ     1     1   109
 2        1 agencydebt     1     1   109
 3        1     assess     1     1   109
 4        1      avail     1     1   109
 5        1     balanc     2     1   109
 # ... with 4,520 more rows
```

Comment: What do you mean by the negative relationship between the term and the rank? 
The linear regression of term_frequency predicting rank? Because your plot does not immediately suggest a negative relationship there... It might even be positive.
That code would be:
lm(formula = rank ~ frequency, data = freq_rk)

Comment: Thank you Nicolas ...... I mean that the graph that I plotted did not look like the standard Zipf 's law graph. So, I would like to find a code that helps to produce that graph.  Thanks

Comment: Tom, Zipf's law suggests an inverse relationship. The book you point at even explains it as a power law, that is, a logarithmic relationship. As per your image, your case is described, at best, by a lineal relationship.
So, it looks like your case does not fall into Zipf's range.
One of the reasons your case might fall out of a logaritmic regression is that you seem to have too few cases (i.e. tokens or words), and they are concentrated in a small window ( your rank is 1 to 30). Look at how large the J. Austen's  ranks are, from 1 to ~2500.

Comment: Thank you Nicolas ... You make the point clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `row_number()` to get rank, you need to make sure that your data frame is ordered by `n`, the number of times a word is used in a document. Let's look at an example. It sounds like you are starting with a document-term matrix that you are tidying? (I'm going to use some example data that is similar to a DTM from quanteda.)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

data("data_corpus_inaugural", package = "quanteda")
inaug_dfm <- quanteda::dfm(data_corpus_inaugural, verbose = FALSE)

ap_td <- tidy(inaug_dfm)
ap_td
#> # A tibble: 44,725 x 3
#>           document   term count
#>              <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 1789-Washington fellow     3
#>  2 1793-Washington fellow     1
#>  3      1797-Adams fellow     3
#>  4  1801-Jefferson fellow     7
#>  5  1805-Jefferson fellow     8
#>  6    1809-Madison fellow     1
#>  7    1813-Madison fellow     1
#>  8     1817-Monroe fellow     6
#>  9     1821-Monroe fellow    10
#> 10      1825-Adams fellow     3
#> # ... with 44,715 more rows
```

Notice that here, you have a tidy data frame with one word per row, but it is not ordered by `count`, the number of times that each word was used in each document. If we used `row_number()` here to try to assign rank, it isn't meaningful because the words are all jumbled up in order.

Instead, we can arrange this by descending count.

```r
ap_td <- tidy(inaug_dfm) %>%
  group_by(document) %>%
  arrange(desc(count)) 

ap_td
#> # A tibble: 44,725 x 3
#> # Groups:   document [58]
#>         document  term count
#>            <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 1841-Harrison   the   829
#>  2 1841-Harrison    of   604
#>  3     1909-Taft   the   486
#>  4 1841-Harrison     ,   407
#>  5     1845-Polk   the   397
#>  6   1821-Monroe   the   360
#>  7 1889-Harrison   the   360
#>  8 1897-McKinley   the   345
#>  9 1841-Harrison    to   318
#> 10 1881-Garfield   the   317
#> # ... with 44,715 more rows
```

*Now* we can use `row_number()` to get rank, because the data frame is actually ranked/arranged/ordered/sorted/however you want to say it.

```r
ap_td <- tidy(inaug_dfm) %>%
  group_by(document) %>%
  arrange(desc(count)) %>%
  mutate(rank = row_number(),
         total = sum(count),
         `term frequency` = count / total)

ap_td
#> # A tibble: 44,725 x 6
#> # Groups:   document [58]
#>         document  term count  rank total `term frequency`
#>            <chr> <chr> <dbl> <int> <dbl>            <dbl>
#>  1 1841-Harrison   the   829     1  9178       0.09032469
#>  2 1841-Harrison    of   604     2  9178       0.06580954
#>  3     1909-Taft   the   486     1  5844       0.08316222
#>  4 1841-Harrison     ,   407     3  9178       0.04434517
#>  5     1845-Polk   the   397     1  5211       0.07618499
#>  6   1821-Monroe   the   360     1  4898       0.07349939
#>  7 1889-Harrison   the   360     1  4744       0.07588533
#>  8 1897-McKinley   the   345     1  4383       0.07871321
#>  9 1841-Harrison    to   318     4  9178       0.03464807
#> 10 1881-Garfield   the   317     1  3240       0.09783951
#> # ... with 44,715 more rows

ap_td %>%
  ggplot(aes(rank, `term frequency`, color = document)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.8, show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Julia! Your elaboration is very clear. Yes, I started with the document term matrix and use  tidy() to convert it into the tidy format.   Thanksss

Comment: Dear Julia .... It works very well. I can reproduce Zipf's law now.  :D

Answer (score 0):

A graph that would describe a linear regression (i.e. not Zipf's Law) would just add a smooth with a linear regression model (lm).

```
freq_rk %>%
ggplot(aes(rank,term_frequency,color=document)) +
geom_line(size=1.2,alpha=0.8) +
geom_smooth(method = lm)
```

To identify the differences between Austen's distributions and yours, run the following code:

Austen:

```
ggplot(freq_by_rank, aes(rank, fill = book) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + labs(title = "Austen linear")
ggplot(freq_by_rank, aes(rank, fill = book) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + scale_x_log10() + labs(title = "Austen Logarithmic")
```

Tom's Sample

```
ggplot(freq_rk, aes(rank, fill = document) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + labs(title = "Sample linear")
ggplot(freq_rk, aes(rank, fill = document) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + scale_x_log10() + labs(title = "Sample Logarithmic")
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nicolas. I will try replicating and will get back to the forum again.    Thank a lots :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your meaningful comments Nicolas :)

Comment: I hope it helps, Tom. I am curious, what are your units of analysis? The documents you are analyzing? I am about to begin an analysis of several hundreds of thousends of Facebook posts, and I was wondering what literature on text analysis for social media post is thought nowadays in communication and literature schools.

Comment: Hi Nicolas    I am working on the central bank statements. I download the statements in csv format, and each row of the file is a statement for one meeting. For example, there are 8 meetings in one year. Thus, my csv file will have 8 rows. As for the application of text mining , I would highly recommend you to visit Ted kwartler : 
            https://github.com/kwartler/ODSC_Workshop
and            this youtube:
           https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTrkTDCyO80&t=1539s
The youtube is the video for ODSC workshop. The example of the workshop is sentiment analysis.
Hope this helps :)